# SQL:find strings that contains unexpected words

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a list of words `a` `b` and `c`.
In my database, there is text column containins many words separated by a space.

I would like to list all records that contains other words that the one I am expected.

```
create table a (id int, memo text);
insert into a values
  (1, 'a aa b'),
  (2, 'b a'),
  (3, 'c a d'),
  (4, 'b cc a');

select * from a where memo /*matches something else than 'a', 'b', 'c'*/ ~ '[^abc ]';
/* should return 1 because of aa */
/*               3 because of d  */
/*               4 because of cc */
```

See a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cf2ab/5).

My current query returns only 3 which is not what I am looking for.
Is there anyway to do this in postgresql ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Dwayne Towell, I came up with this query.

```
SELECT * FROM a
WHERE NOt(ARRAY['a','b','c'] @> regexp_split_to_array(memo, E'\\s+')::text[]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the string into rows and use `IN`, like this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id,regexp_split_to_table(memo, E'\\s+') AS word FROM a
) x 
WHERE word NOT in ('a','b','c');
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cf2ab/29).

Comment: thank you ! I found it was faster to use regexp_split_to_array without subqueries.